# "Whose three interior angles each measure" or "measures"?

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement, determiners, parts-of-speech

I get stuck by this sentence:

> Equilateral triangle: A triangle whose three sides are all equal in length and whose three interior angles each measure 60°.

Is *measure* in this sentence a verb or a noun? If it is a verb it should be *measures* or *measuring*, and if it is a noun the attribute should be *each measure is 60°*. What am I missing here? Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, the quoted definition is redundant, as any triangle whose three sides are equal in length will have equal interior angles, which will always prove to be  60°.

Comment: @DavidSiegel But it is a definition for a beginner, so I thought the redundancy should be considered acceptable in such a special scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Measure* is a verb in your example, specifically in the sense of having a particular measurement, or as [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/measure) puts it,

> 3. [linking verb] to be a particular size, length, or amount
>
>    > - The room measures 6 x 6 metres.
>    > - The earthquake measured 6.5 on the Richter scale.

Your instinct that *each* signifies singular is not necessarily a bad one, as usually when used as a determiner or pronoun, *each* signifies something individual, thus taking singular verb agreement. When *each* follows a plural noun or noun phrase, however, it does not affect concord, any more than similar words or phrases like *individually*, *one by one*, *apiece*, *singly*, or *separately* would. Some dictionaries classify this as an adverbial usage, others simply as a special case, e.g. [Cambridge Dictionary Online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/each):

> When we use *each* to refer to the subject of the clause, it usually appears in the normal mid position for adverbs, between the subject and the main verb, after the modal verb or first auxiliary verb, or after *be* as a main verb:
>
> > - We each agreed to help by contributing some money towards the cost.
> > - We would each say a poem or sing a song.
> > - Have you each signed the contract?
> > - Husband and wife are each entitled to invest up to the maximum of £40,000.

Your example could take a singular verb if *each* is moved to a different position, though I would argue the resulting rephrasing would be rather stilted, or at the least needlessly wordy:

> Equilateral triangle: A triangle whose three sides are all equal in length and each of whose three interior angles measures 60°.
>
> Equilateral triangle: A triangle, each of whose three sides is equal in length, and each of whose three interior angles measures 60°.
>
> Equilateral triangle: A triangle in which all three sides are equal in length and in which each interior angle measures 60°.

and so on and so forth. Using the present continuous *measuring* would indeed sidestep the matter.

Comment: A great answer, but I think maybe it would be even more helpful if you edited it to point out that in this case "measure" is an intransitive verb meaning "to have a specified measurement" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/measure). I suspect that unfamiliarity with this meaning of "measure" might be one reason for the OP's uncertainty about whether "measure" is a verb or a noun in this sentence.

Comment: @Nanigashi That is an excellent point, thank you. I have added a dictionary definition and link.